# Setting all cards of equal height (mdbootstrap)

Tags: bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I am using mdbootstrap in my Angular Project so when I display multiple cards on my screen ,they are not of same height due to difference in the height of card images as you can see in the link given below:

**https://ibb.co/NpqWy7z**

Here is the code for that

```
 <div class="col">
 <mdb-card  style="width:17rem;" class="c1">
 <div class="view rgba-white-slight waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>      
 <mdb-card-img [src]="p?.imageurl" alt="Card image cap" 
 class="cardimg"></mdb-card-img>
 <a>
 <div class="mask"></div>
 </a>
 </div>
 <mdb-card-body>
 <mdb-card-title>
 <h4>Card Title</h4>
 </mdb-card-title>

 <mdb-card-text> Some quick example text to build on the card title
        content.
 </mdb-card-text>

 <a href="#" mdbBtn color="primary" mdbWavesEffect>Button</a>
 </mdb-card-body>
 </mdb-card>
 </div>
```

As you can see i have already tried giving  a css class of cardimg  and applying css on it

```
.cardimg{
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

but still this does not solve my issue

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Can you add a code snippet with your example ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **object-fit: cover;** from below css

```
.cardimg{ width: 100%; height: 50px; object-fit: cover; }
```